# Nautilus image & video thumbnails (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)?

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

Trying to get image and video (mp4) preview / artwork thumbnails but no go?

I've tried,

- Nautilus preview preferences
- `ubuntu-restricted-extras`
- `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime`
- `apt install --reinstall shared-mime-info`
- `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime` (gives an error I think ~/.local/share/mime/packages can't be found)

Also tried out Nemo and I have a similar problem there although icons for images do have a snapshot. I've seen comments to use ffmpegthumbnailer, just wanting to know if it does a snapshot of a video or will I get the artwork in the metadata?

Update ...
I installed `ffmpegthumbnailer` and it works ok, not sure about settings if I can have the Artwork displayed but this is what I need displayed not a snapshot.

Comment: Do you have `totem` ("Videos" application) installed?

Comment: @espr3ss0 .. please update your question with requested informations instead of putting them as comment - this also makes it easier for you to format them appropriately.

Comment: I think a bot has been at work because this question has nothing to do with totem. There is a solution but unfortunately not for me ... There is an update ffmpegthumbnailer 2.2 but only for certain distros which includes Artwork ability ... https://pkgs.org/download/ffmpegthumbnailer